# ¿Diferencias entre Form::model y Form::open?

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5

Buenas tardes, estoy aprendiendo laravel y al utilizar la libreria de laravel collecitve, al crear formularios, veo que en ocasiones se abre el formulario con `Form::model` y otras con `Form::open`. Por más que busco no encuentro la diferencia ni se si hay más tipos y de ser así ¿cuando se utiliza cada uno? Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La diferencia es que con `Form::model` vas a recibir la información del modelo que pases como primer parámetro y por consiguiente si Laravel encuentra una coincidencia entre el nombre del campo en el modelo y en el formulario, entonces el campo del formulario es "llenado" con el valor almacenado en el modelo. `Form::model` también toma los valores de la sesión que tengan los mismo nombres que los campos del formulario.

Como podemos ver en el código a continuación, `Form::model` llama a `Form::open` también:

```
/**
 * Create a new model based form builder.
 *
 * @param  mixed $model
 * @param  array $options
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Support\HtmlString
 */
public function model($model, array $options = [])
{
    $this->model = $model;

    return $this->open($options);
}
```